# Why does scroll-behavior: smooth put the anchor on the bottom of the page?

Tags: android, html, css, firefox

When using Firefox on mobile (Android), `scroll-behavior:smooth` will bring the anchor to the *bottom* of the page. A second tap of the link will bring the anchor smoothly to the top of the page, as expected.

Setting `scroll-behavior: auto` resolves the issue.

Firefox on desktop seems unaffected.

Video of the issue:

https://photos.app.goo.gl/VtLx5R3XFYgZcqUZ6

Demo here:

https://codepen.io/Malchoix/pen/QWoBPPo